# JetBrains Rider IDE does not redirect input from file

Tags: c#, input, rider

I'm trying to redirect input stream to a file for a program run. It works outside of rider using the same command but not inside. In particular, I have the following Program `Excutable.exe`:

```
using System;

internal class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine("Input correct.");
    }
}
```

and the file `input.txt`:

```
Input test
```

**Runs:**

On the command line I have:

```
c:\>"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\mono.exe" "C:/Project/Debug/Executable.exe" < "C:\input.txt"
Input correct.

c:\>
```

but in Rider console I have:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Mono\bin\mono.exe" "C:/Project/Debug/Executable.exe" < "C:\input.txt"
|
```

i.e. the program is waiting for input from the console, ignoring the input stream.

The `< "C:\input.txt"` in Rider is provided in the `Program arguments` field.

I have tried on/off `Use Mono` and on/off `Use external console`.

I would like for the program to be able to read the input file instead of input stream on every run, without having to type the input manually.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you're doing. You are just executing a simple console application, right? In that case, check the run configuration. You shouldn't invoke the executable via mono, but just as is (since you're on Windows I assume).

Comment: The Rider invokes Mono - the output in console is in My understanding the literal command Rider invokes. 

The run configuration is specified as listed above, i.e. I add only < "C"\input.txt" as program arguments.